# Dynamically build html table rows and columns ngrepeat

Tags: angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm very new to angular js and I have a problem with building a html table with ngrepeat. I have to build a html table for roles and permission and in this I have to list all actions on the header part like (show, Add, Edit, Delete, Print, Email .. ) and  each row I have to display the module and a check box under each action if that module has that actions. for example some module will not have a email option and for that we should not display the checkbox under that action. Please help me with this and it will be useful for my learning purpose as well.

```
*------------------------------------------------------------*   
| Module       | Show | Add  | Edit | Delete | Print | Email |
+--------------|------|------|------|--------|-------|-------+
| Purchase     | *    |  *   |  *   |   *    |   *   |   *   |
|--------------|------|------|------|--------|-------|-------|
| Sales        | *    |  *   |  *   |   *    |   *   |   *   |
|--------------|------|------|------|--------|-------|-------|
| XXXXXX       | *    |  *   |  *   |   *    |       |       |
|--------------|------|------|------|--------|-------|-------|
| xxx-Reports  | *    |      |      |        |   *   |   *   |
*------------------------------------------------------------*   

* reperesents checkboxes
```

I'm getting two json from the webservice, once for header and the other for Modules and actions.

```
Header 

{"Headers":[{"action_id":0,"name":"list"},{"action_id":1,"name":"Add"},{"action_id":2,"name":"Edit"},{"action_id":3,"name":"Delete"},{"action_id":4,"name":"Email"},{"action_id":4,"name":"Print"}]}

Body

{"Purchase":[{"name":"list","action_id":0,"status":1},{"name":"Add","action_id":1,"status":1},{"name":"Edit","action_id":2,"status":0},{"name":"Delete","action_id":3,"status":0}],"Sales":[{"name":"list","action_id":0,"status":1},{"name":"Add","action_id":1,"status":1},{"name":"Edit","action_id":2,"status":0},{"name":"Delete","action_id":3,"status":0}],"DC":[{"name":"Add","action_id":1,"status":1},{"name":"Edit","action_id":2,"status":0},{"name":"Delete","action_id":3,"status":0},{"name":"Email","action_id":4,"status":0},{"name":"Print","action_id":5,"status":0}]}
```

If we click show check box, all other corresponding action checkbox should be checked.

I have no problem in building the columns but I have no idea on how to build the rows and place checkbox on appropriate columns.

Comment: Create your model in your controller with your parsed json data. Then you can use ngChecked directive to decide if checkbox should be checked or not: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked

Comment: If I understood you right, here is a plunker for something similar to what you have, you need 1 ng-repeat for the header, and 2 nested ng-repeat for the body of table. about the ckeboxes, please see what @MertMertce wrote. http://plnkr.co/edit/01AztdZkKlBosj2oFFnf?p=preview

Comment: Dear Dimma Gimms , thanks for your kind help. will you help me with another one changes please. i need extra column called show and if show check box is click i need to check all the checkbox in that particular row. Again thanks for your time.

Comment: @PrabhuRaj In ngChecked directive put also that condition: eg: ngChecked="original_value || row_show_checked"

Comment: Dear Dimma Gimms, the code is not working as expected. if the module dosenot have list option, it is putting checkbox in the list option as well. if you have some time please have a look at that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to build the table header which is straight forward. just use ngrepeat on the header json .

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Module </th>
            <th ng-repeat = "key in head.Headers" > {{key.name}} </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

And then using the same header json , iterate through each module, find whether the action is availabe for that particular module and display the checkbox .

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat = "(key_body,val_body) in jsonbody">
        <td>{{key_body}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat = "key in head.Headers">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-modal="output[key_body][key.name]"  ng-if = "(val_body|filter:key.name:true).length>0" >
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This may not be a professional method but def it will solve your purpose.

Plunker link is given below

http://plnkr.co/edit/I2MAUcPgBAUjvjfBHlFe?p=preview